# Efficiently determine a matrix using equations made out of its elements

Tags: systems-of-equations, programming

Suppose $\sigma$ is a real, symmetric and positive matrix ($\sigma > 0$). The *elements* of $\sigma$ satisfy a certain number of quadratic equations, this number is less than the number of independent elements in $\sigma$. Moreover, $\sigma$ satisfies an additional constraint:

$$\sigma + i \Omega \ge 0,$$

where $\Omega$ is a real matrix.

Is there a tool which can determine whether $\sigma$ has a solution? And if a solution exists, can we find at least one such solution? This may be more of a programming question, so I don't know if this is the right place to ask.

---

**Additional details which may be useful**:

$\sigma$ is an $8 \times 8$ matrix, so it has 36 independent elements.

The number of equations in the elements of $\sigma$ is 16.

$\Omega$ is the symplectic form, i.e. for all symplectic real matrices $S$, $S \Omega S^T = \Omega$.

Comment: What have you tried? You don't appear to have shown any working thus far.
You could try testing a couple of examples of Omega, then substituting into the constraint equation so see if the result is more than 0.

Comment: @unseen_rider I have tried using `sympy` module in Python to solve the equations, but the program never terminates since the number of equations and variables is way too high. Even if that was not a problem, I don't know how to incorporate the constraint. Also, I don't understand your comment about Omega, since Omega is known exactly. 

As far as showing any working, I am looking for a programming tool which gives me a numerical solution. So, I have not performed any analytical work.

Comment: "I am looking for a programming tool which gives me a numerical solution" this is then needed in your original question. One could currently interpret your request as a method. Also since Omega is known, if you know its numerical elements in matrix form, add to the question so people can suggest methods that are likely to / will work as well as the general matrix for any elements